# set session value in symfony2 view

Tags: symfony, session, twig

I want to set session value in Symfony2 view both in PHP and TWIG . I can get the session value in view like this

> $app->getSession()->get('whatever');

But didn't know how to set the session value in view . Kindly any one help .

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski I want to set session value in twig and PHP not access or get it. so its not the same as your one .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your twig extension you can put this code under `YourBundle/Twig/SessionExtension.php`

```
namespace YourBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class SessionExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('setSession', array($this, 'setSession')),
        );
    }

    public function setSession($key, $val){

        $this->session->set($key, $val);
        return true;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'session_extension';
    }
}
```

Add to service for twig;

```
yourbundle.twig.session_extension:
      class: YourBundle\Twig\SessionExtension
      arguments:
          session: "@session"
      tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now , you can use in twig;

```
{{ 'test'|setSession('myKey', 'myValue') }}
```

Comment: I want to set the session not get the session in twig

Comment: You can create a twig extension and send @session to this extension with service container. You can set a new session key and value like that way.

Comment: I changed my answer as what you want.